# Returning Value in C

Tags: c, function, return, return-value

I have a problem with the return value in a binary search that I wrote.

I have the following:

int binarySearch(char *instructions[], int low, int high, char *string);

```
int main() {
    char *instructions[];  // some array of strings - it does not include the string "jk"
    char *string = "jk";
    int high = inst_len;
    int x = binarySearch(instructions, 0, high, string);
    if (x == -1)
        printf("not found");
    else if (x == -2)
    printf("error");
    else
    printf("Found at %d", x);
}

int binarySearch(char *instructions[], int low, int high, char *string) {

    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

    // Not found
    if (high <= low)
        return -1;

    // If instructions[mid] is less than string
    else if (strcmp(instructions[mid], string) > 0)
        binarySearch(instructions, low, mid-1, string);

    // If instructions[mid] is larger than string
    else if (strcmp(instructions[mid], string) < 0)
        binarySearch(instructions, mid+1, high, string);

    // Return position
    else
        return mid;
}
```

No matter what, in `main`, binarySearch is always returning 0. However, when I put print statements in the binary search algorithm, I get `-1` being returned. Why is this happening?? This is very weird!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this:

```
// If instructions[mid] is less than string
else if (strcmp(instructions[mid], string) > 0)
    return binarySearch(instructions, low, mid-1, string);

// If instructions[mid] is larger than string
else if (strcmp(instructions[mid], string) < 0)
    return binarySearch(instructions, mid+1, high, string);
```

Note the "`return`" part.

You're also doing the compare more times than you have to; you can store the result of `strcmp` so that you only do it once:

```
int r = strcmp(instructions[mid], string);

if (r > 0)
    return binarySearch(instructions, low, mid-1, string);
else if (r < 0)
    return binarySearch(instructions, mid+1, high, string);
```

Comment: As an aside: If you have warnings enabled in your compiler, it should be telling you that this function doesn't always return a value. If you don't have warnings enabled, turn them on!

Comment: @Nayefc - If you're missing a `return` statement and you use the return value, the behavior is undefined.  Usually the return value you get will be garbage, eg. on many x86 environments it will just be whatever happens to be in the register `eax`.