# C implementation of Java Arrays.binarySearch method

Tags: java, c, arrays, binary-search

I would like to implement the java [Arrays.binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) method for `binarySearch(double[], double)`, but in C language. Something similar is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642386/returning-value-in-c) but for a character array, and it is not described well enough. How should I do it? Is it already implemented anywhere else (GSL library, etc)?

Comment: I have just edited now the question.

Comment: Do you really need it in C or does c++ also work for you?

Comment: Why don't use same method by 'double' type?! 'Binary Search Algorithm' is simple, You are better learning its algorithm. see:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm , then you can doing binary search by any language.

Comment: I would like to use it in a big C project. I could rewrite it from C++ to C and put it here, if I get the C++ code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a C++ compiler, take a look at [std::binary_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/).

**Update**

Also take a look at `stdlib.h` (ANSI C) [bsearch](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/bsearch/). Since you are working directly with arrays, I think this is the function that best fits the job.

Comment: I have found it something: in C language, there is a similar function to that of Java and C++:
[bsearch](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/bsearch.html)
from stdlib.h.

Comment: Thanks! I was writting it at the same time!

Comment: +1 because so many people are completely ignorant of what is already provided in the standard C library and end up reinventing everything (seriously: I've seen people reimplement all of stdio with wrappers around read and write).